# How to keep text inside a div, always in the middle?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make text stay in the middle of a resizable DIV.
Here's the example:

CSS

```
#rightmenu {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 999999;
  right: 0;
  height: 60%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="rightmenu">This text should be center aligned and in the middle of the resizable rightmenu</div>
```

I've tried to make a Class to contain the text with the "margin-top and margin-bottom" both on auto, but doesn't work.

Comment: You mean you want the text vertically centered? Thanks to the W3C's infinite intelligence, that's impossible with standard CSS and requires multiple hacks, workarounds, and extra markup.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you don't care about IE7 support, you can do it like that:

HTML:

```
<div id=wrap>
  <div id=inside>
    Content, content, content.
  </div> 
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#wrap {
    /* Your styling. */
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 999999;
    right: 0;
    height: 60%;
    text-align: center;

    /* Solution part I. */
    display: table;
}

/* Solution part II. */
#inside {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

The code: http://tinkerbin.com/ETMVplub

If you're OK with JavaScript you can try this jQuery plugin: http://centratissimo.musings.it/ but since it also doesn't seems to support IE7 the CSS solution is probably better.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much! It's exactly what I need, and as always expected that IE will have some problems.. lol. Thanks man.

Answer (score 6):

[Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) has really changed the game with aligning elements in a fluid manner. Define your container element to be `display: flex` and then to align your inner children you would use `justify-content: center; align-items: center;`

```
.container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.parent {
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
    position: relative;
}


<div class="parent">
    <div class="container">
        <p>Hello</p>
        <p>World</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

You'll notice that "Hello" and "World" will both be vertically and horizontally centered within the `.container` element.

Comment: `display: flex; justify-content: center;` did the trick for me. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Replace `height: 60%;` with `padding: 30% 0;`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the text to be horizontally centered in a div, 'text-align:center;' is your friend. If you want it vertically centered; wrap the content inside an inner div, and then use 'margin: auto' for that inner div. Of course, you'll have to give the inner div a width; otherwise, the horizontal center won't work. 
'valign="middle"' also works in tables if tables are an option (otherwise discouraged)

Answer (score 0):

**Check if this is needed:**

```
<html>

<head>
  <style type="text/css">
    div {
      height: 100px;
      width: 100px;
      background: #ccc;
      text-align: center;
    }

    p {
      line-height: 100px;
    }

  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <p>centered</p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```