# How center text of column according to height of div in html?

Tags: html, css

I want text in the center of div as div size increases and decreases in HTML. I want vertically centered align.

Comment: Do you want to center the text vertically or horizontally?

Comment: I want vertically. horizontally i know..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10539333/4229270  &  http://stackoverflow.com/a/17521229/4229270

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to vertically center text with CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8865458/how-to-vertically-center-text-with-css)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

apply
 display:flex;
to parent div

Answer (score 1):

Add this css to the div

```
.div_name {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle }
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want horizontal then use `text-align:center` and if you want verticaly please check that [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pyS9c/11/)